# Disable E303 warning when swap directory isn't writeable

Tags: vimrc, swap-file

I sometimes run vim as another user than me, using my own vimrc. In this case the swp and undo directory aren't writeable, and vim warns me with E303.

I don't care about not having swap file in this case, is there a way to disable this specific warning?

Or how can I check from vimrc that the directory isn't writeable?

Comment: I'm not sure if you can easily disable this error, but one solution would be to store swap files in `~/.vim/tmp/` (or `~/.cache/vim/`) rather than the path of the file you're editing. See: https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/56/51 That will prevent conflicts between different users, as both users will have their own swap in their own home directory.

Comment: What user are you running as? If it’s root, I’d recommend `sudoedit` instead

Comment: @MartinTournoij thanks, that's indeed the solution. I was using `~/.vim/swp` for swap files, but `$HOME` was incorrectly kept to original user (me) in the sudo call. Using `--set-home` in sudo did the trick, so swap directory is now in a writeable place.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble It's for another user than root. I didn't know about `sudoedit`, thanks.